# Почему не кластеризуются соседние метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Поэкспериментируем в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create

Добавим в общий массив метку 1: `[47.23500824,39.72497559]`, метку 2: `[47.5500824,39.72497559]` и 3: `[47.22273254,39.72646713]`
(эти точки располагаются в Ростове).

Метки 1 и 2 кластеризуются как положено. А вот метка 3 не кластеризуется ни с кем и накладывается на метку 1 (или на кластер меток 1 и 2).

[image: добавим метки]

[image: меньший зум]

Полноценная кластеризация происходит только на zoom ~7.

Параметр `gridSize` плавно изменял от 64 до 1024 - влияния на метку 3 это не оказывает (на все остальные - оказывает).

Экспериментировал с параметром `minClusterSize`, выставлял ему значение 1. Метки превращаются в кластеры по отдельности, но в единый кластер всё равно не объединяются.

[image: одна метка в кластере]

Экспериментировал так же с различными настройками, типа margin, zoomMargin и т.п. - всё бесполезно. Проверял в Chrome и Firefox.

Подобные "магические" метки существуют также в Волгограде.

Как это понимать?

Answer (score 1):

Так устроена Grid-кластеризация. Метки кластеризуются только если они попали в один тайл. Если метки попали в соседние тайлы, то пока эти тайлы не объединятся, метки не объединятся в кластер. Как формируется тайловая сетка можно почитать тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/theory/concepts/coordinates-docpage/ или тут: https://habr.com/post/268621/

Если вам хочется сделать свою кластеризацию, то можно воспользоваться RemoteObjectManager https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/RemoteObjectManager-docpage/ . Он позволяет написать свою серверную кластеризацию. А на карте будет отображаться то, что вы вернете с сервера.

Comment: А почему тогда gridSize особо не влияет на ситуацию? Или существуют такие соседние тайлы, которые объединяются только при крайне маленьком зуме?

При выборе основы для проекта, одним из плюсов в пользу Яндекс.Карт, была как раз готовая возможность кластеризации. На текущем этапе писать собственную реализацию кластеризации = выползать за рамки бюджета. А то, что есть сейчас клиент характеризует как "кластеризация не работает".

Comment: gridSize будет выправлять ситуацию на некоторых соседних тайлах, но всегда существуют такие соседние тайлы, которые объединяются только при крайне маленьком зуме. Этот кейс возникает редко и вам просто "повезло".